# Not detecting NVIDIA video card

Tags: debian, nvidia, video

I am almost certain my Debian 8 computer is just detecting one video card. The computer has two video cards, specifically an Intel HD Graphics 520 (integrated) and NVIDIA GeForce 940-mx (2GB).

I think only one is being detected since when I use the command `lspci -k | grep -A 2 -i "VGA"` it returns

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 1916 (rev 07)
Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 820a
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Device 1903 (rev 08)
```

and the command `lspci|grep VGA` returns

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 1916 (rev 07)
```

When I ran the above codes the NVIDIA drivers were already supposedly installed, had download them directly from [their page](http://www.nvidia.com/download/driverResults.aspx/104284/en-us) and installed them, since the package `nvidia-detect` didn't detect any video card in my computer.

Is my NVIDIA card really not being detected? how can I fix this?

Comment: Update the database `sudo update-pciids`  and try again with `lspci ..`

Comment: Nothing changed, only downloaded something called  `daily snapshot`

Comment: I will go to BIOS and check because I don't know.

Comment: Install the `nvidia-smi` package and run : `sudo nvidia-smi`

Comment: Had tried that with `sudo apt-get install nvidia-smi` but it returns `E: Unable to locate package nvidia-smi`

Comment: `nvidia-smi` is a non free software , you should add `non-free`  to `/etc/apt/sources.list`  see [here](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/amd64/nvidia-smi/download)

Comment: I did all that last night, added non free path to my repositories, then `sudo apt-get update`, installed packages and finally ran `apt-get install nvidia-driver` and `apt-get install nvidia-xconfig`, restarted it and my computer doesnt boot anymore. I actually dont have time to install Debian all over again and all the packages I had already installed so I will just create a virtual machine in the Windows partition I left, and will install everything all over again later when I have time. Had spent more than 2 days installing things and fixing bugs that it had for my system.

Comment: Just remove the 2 installed packages `nvidia-xconfig && nvidia-driver` , then send a bug report to debian

Comment: Was able to recover my sistem by purging everything that was related to NVIDIA and setting my `xorg.conf` like I had it before (it had nothing written). Did that a few hours ago, can I still send a bug report? how would it be done?

Comment: You can use the terminal or via mail there is some examples and format here https://www.debian.org/Bugs/Reporting

Answer (score 1):

You ought to be able to see the card even without a driver installed, could you try `lspci | egrep 'VGA|3D|NVIDIA'` -- if you still don't see it, I would ensure that the card is seated firmly and that any auxiliary power connectors are attached.

However, I suspect the problem is that you have a laptop with hybrid graphics. To support this it seems [Bumblebee and primus](https://wiki.debian.org/Bumblebee) seem to be required.

Comment: I tried the command and it didnt appear, downloading Bumbleblee and primus as we speak. Not sure how I'd use it to install the video card though, but I will keep reading.

Comment: Interesting! It seems that NVIDA or "3D" should certainly appear in LSPCI if the card is present, are you certain it's physically installed?

Comment: Yes, it is physically installed. The computer is new and when it came with Windows you could see it installed.

Comment: could you upload/post the output of `dmesg` command?

Comment: If `lspci` does not show the card, that means the card is not even detecting as a generic PCI(e) device. It might be disabled by your BIOS settings: if there's a setting called something like "disable Optimus" or "use iGPU only", that might be disabling the NVIDIA GPU at the PCI(e) bus level.